# Convert XML file to a list of dictionaries using python

Tags: python, xml

I am tasked to convert an XML to a list of dictionaries.
The structure of XML:

```xml
   <root>
     <child>
       <record attribute1 = value1 attribute2 = value2 attribute3 = value3....attribute63 = value63/>
       <record attribute1 = value1 attribute2 = value2 attribute3 = value3....attribute63 = value63/>
       <record attribute1 = value1 attribute2 = value2 attribute3 = value3....attribute63 = value63/>
     </child>
   </root>
```

I used `xml.etree.ElementTree` module and parsed the data.
`root[0][0].attrib` returns me a dictionary of 1st record with each attribute and its corresponding value as key value pairs.

I am trying to create a loop and retrieve all records in the same format, but as a list.
Basically a list of dictionaries where each dictionary corresponds to one record tag in the xml file.

My code:

```
i = root
j = root.attrib
for i, j in root[i].[j].attrib:
    myDict = {}
    try:
       myDict["attribute1"] = root[i][j].attrib
    except:
       pass
    try:
       myDict["attribute63"] = root[i][j].attrib
    except:
       pass
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: element indices must be integers
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach.
`root[0][0].attrib` returns the 1st record element and all its attributes and their corresponding values in the form of dictionary.
I want my code to return a list of all record elements as respective dictionaries.

Comment: Pleas post what is the exact form of the `root[0][0]`, the dict related logic is definitely broken, but I cannot imagine what exactly needs fixing from your description.

Comment: The exact for root[0][0] is 

<child>
       <record attribute1 = value1 attribute2 = value2 attribute3 = value3....attribute63 = value63/>
When I try root[0][0].attrib, it returns
{
attribute1 : value1, 
attribute2: value2
.....
attribute63: value63}

Comment: type(root[0][23].attrib) is dict

Comment: Just do a print of that and insert it as a code to the question. I still have no clue sorry.

Comment: Hello Sir, I think I got it:)
This worked - 
for i in range(len(root[0])):
    myList = []
    for j in range(len(root[0])):
        myList.append(root[0][j].attrib)

Comment: Thank you for your time on this. 
I will now need to convert this into a function. 
Will work on it now.

Answer (score 0):

How about parsing with pandas, there is a easy `read_xml()` and `to_dict()`.

```
import pandas as pd

# Your XML saved into convertXML.xml without the dots 
with open("convertXML.xml", "r") as xml: 
    xml = xml.read()

df = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath=".//record")
print(df)

# Get the dictionary
df2 = df.to_dict('records')
print(df2)
```

Output:
the DataFrame:

```
  attribute1 attribute2 attribute3 attribute63
0     value1     value2     value3     value63
1     value1     value2     value3     value63
2     value1     value2     value3     value63
```

The list of dictionaries:

```
[{'attribute1': 'value1', 'attribute2': 'value2', 'attribute3': 'value3', 'attribute63': 'value63'}, {'attribute1': 'value1', 'attribute2': 'value2', 'attribute3': 'value3', 'attribute63': 'value63'}, {'attribute1': 'value1', 'attribute2': 'value2', 'attribute3': 'value3', 'attribute63': 'value63'}]
```

Comment: Thank you. 
I did figure this out with for loop and calling on the attrib method, I could generate a list of dictionaries.
def convertRWS(xmlFilePath):
    tree = ET.parse(xmlFilePath)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for i in range(len(root[0])):
        myList = []
        for j in range(len(root[0])):
            myList.append(root[0][j].attrib)
    return myList

Thank you for taking time and responding. Much appreciated.